# Check if 2 textboxes have the same data type

Tags: c#, string, validation

I am trying to make a Kinematics Calculator on C#, you input 3 numerical values, a letter and a question mark (each in different text boxes). The letters change depend on the value you are inputting. For example, you would input "A" for acceleration but "T" for time. Unfortunately, the problem is I need a function that finds if 2 letters are present in 2 different text boxes and display a message box saying you cannot do that, etc

For example,

If I had a textbox that had a user input of "A" and another textbox that had a user input of "T", then I need a message box that outputs "Only 1 letter allowed, please try again".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered “checking” if a text box actually has text and if it does have text, then also “check” if it is a valid value BEFORE you try to calculate the values? If one of the “checks” fails, then warn the user.

Comment: A control which only allows the user to select one or the other options seems like it would be more appropriate.  A DropDownList combo control for instance

Comment: @JohnG I've had a function where it checks if a string is null or empty and sends a warning message to the user, and my validation is so if an invalid input is typed then the program would inform the user where it's located.

Comment: If you have the “checks” for empty and validity, then are you actually using them for this issue? In other words, a check is made and the text is not empty, then another check is made to see if the value is valid (“T” or “A”), then after that another check is made that checks if two given values are letters?

Comment: As already noted, if the values are FIXED, then, it sounds like a better approach would be to “help” the user and if the user types “A” in text box 1, then the user CAN NOT type “T” into text box 2. A couple of “filtered” combo boxes may work better than having the user "type" the values. This would eliminate the need to even “check” the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Char.IsLetter()` method alongside the LINQ `Any()`to achieve that. `Char.IsLetter()` method will return `true` if the provided char is an uppercase or lowercase letter. Note that if any of the chars of the string is a letter, the expression return will return `true`, if you need to check if all the characters of the string are a letter, use `.All()` instead of `.Any()`

```
string textbox1Value = "V";
string textbox2Value = "T";
bool hasTwoLetters = textbox1Value.Any(x => char.IsLetter(x)) &&  textbox2Value.Any(x => char.IsLetter(x));
if(hasTwoLetters)
{
    // Display alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a "tryParse" on each text field. If it fails you know there is a character present. You then count the amount of "fails". There are many different ways to detect how many alpha characters there are. You may need to strip the "?" field with .Replace("?","") too.

```
int parsedValue = 0;
int lettersPresent = 0;

if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out parsedValue)) lettersPresent++;
if(!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out parsedValue)) lettersPresent++;

if (lettersPresent > 1) MessageBox.Show("Only 1 letter allowed, please try again");
```

It may be easier to just combine the textbox values and check with contains as well:

```
string combined = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text;
int letterCount = 0;

if (combined.Contains("T")) letterCount++;
if (combined.Contains("S")) letterCount++;

if (letterCount > 1) MessageBox.Show("Too many..");
```

I am assuming you are parsing the letters out at some point so it probably should just be included inside that method.